# spring boot integration test rest

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am using spring boot 1.3.x and trying to setup some integration tests using `@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort=true)` and `TestRestTemplate`.

few problems that I faced initially -

`@Autowired TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;` did not work  so , had to go with `TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();`

then , `@Value("${local.server.port}")` also did not work. it threw exception that it cannot be resolved. so instead had to do this -
`@Autowired Environment environment;`

and in the `@Test` method tried to get the port from the environment but all i got is `null`. so that also did not work.

then changed the port to `8080` by using `application.properties` and using only `@WebIntegrationTest` and manually setup the url for `TestRestTemplate`.

after doing all this, I am getting Connection Refused error now.

pls help. spring documentation is not helping .

thanks

Comment: Let me guess no `@SpringApplicationContextConfiguration` annotation on your test class...

Comment: Thanks Deinum, you are right. I had missed that . I looked it up in the javadoc. but now am facing another problem . I am trying to add a datasource in embedded tomcat and trying to inject it back in one of the @configuration class. but , i am getting the below error -

Name [comp/env/jdbc/myDataSource] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp].

i was going through other stackoverflow threads but the solutions over there did not work for me.

Comment: Why bother with JNDI in an embedded tomcat?

Comment: I did not understand. I am trying to setup integration tests

Comment: You are stating you get an error with JNDI... Why do you bother with JNDI?

Comment: @Bean
 public DataSource dataSource() throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
  JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
     bean.setJndiName("java:comp/env/jdbc/myDataSource");
     bean.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
     bean.setLookupOnStartup(false);
     bean.afterPropertiesSet();
     return (DataSource)bean.getObject();

Comment: As stated why are you bothering with JNDI when you are using an Embedded tomcat... That only makes things more complex, just use a normal datasource instead of a JNDI one.

Comment: Also don't add additional information as comments as that makes it totally unreadable. Add it to your question instead.

Comment: sure , will avoid adding additional information as comments.